# LEFT JOIN ON() in JPQL

Tags: java, sql, jpa, entity, jpql

I have two entities:

- `User`: id:*long*, name:*String*
- `Player`: id:*long*, owner:*User*, points:*int*

Now I want to select a User and his associated Player in one JPQL query. In SQL I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT u.*, p.* FROM User u
LEFT JOIN Player p ON (p.owner_id = u.id)
WHERE u.name = ...
```

My first instinct was to do it like this in JPQL

```
SELECT u, p FROM User u LEFT JOIN Player p ON (p.owner = u) WHERE u.name = ...
```

But I don't think the `ON` clause is supported in JPQL. I do need it however, because `User` has no reference to `Player` (many things other than `Player` could be attached to a `User`).
How can I solve this one?

Answer (score 3):

You have a relationship from `Player` to `User`, so you can invert the join to follow it:

```
SELECT u, p FROM Player p RIGHT JOIN p.owner u WHERE ...
```

Comment: useless answer when you want to join unrelated entities on common field