# Unexpected AST Node LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, jpql

I'm stuck on a query which I'm trying to translate from SQL to JPQL. First are two SQL queries that run fine, last is my failing query along with error:

```
 //SUCCEEDS-----!
 //select * from defermentaccount LEFT OUTER JOIN division ON defermentaccount.deferment_ID=division.divisionID;
 //select * from defermentaccount d LEFT OUTER JOIN division v ON d.deferment_ID=v.divisionID;
 //FAILS--------!     
 Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT defm FROM DefermentAccount defm LEFT JOIN defm.division division ON division.divisionID=:defm.defermentID");
```

Any help much appreciated!

STACK:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: : near line 1, column 129 [SELECT defm FROM uk.co.ash.Server.domain.DefermentAccount defm LEFT JOIN defm.division division ON (division.divisionID=:defm.defermentID)]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:342)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:289)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.createQuery(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.ash.dao.JPQLJUnitTest.stage1_pull_back_all_users(JPQLJUnitTest.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
```

---- HERE IS THE ERROR -- SO insisted, that I give some more detail...

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: : near line 1, column 129 [SELECT defm FROM uk.co.ash.Server.domain.DefermentAccount defm LEFT JOIN defm.division division ON (division.divisionID=:defm.defermentID)]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:328)
... 40 more
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I think that's what I had already...? Query q1 = em.createQuery("SELECT defm FROM DefermentAccount defm LEFT JOIN defm.division division ON division.divisionID=:defm.defermentID");------org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: : near line 1,

Comment: Is `defm` actually a column name? You've made it a table alias.

Comment: There's no defm column, but neither also a defermentaccount column. DDL --
(
    deferment_ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    deferment_Account_End_Date DATETIME,
    deferment_Account_Max_Balance DECIMAL(12,2),
    deferment_Account_Notes VARCHAR(255),
    deferment_Account_Number VARCHAR(255),
    deferment_Account_Start_Date DATETIME,
    division_Deferment_Join_Column BIGINT,
    FOREIGN KEY (division_Deferment_Join_Column) REFERENCES division (divisionID)
);
CREATE INDEX FK_lc3jh0hjn8mbrhqqwjbes7mle ON defermentaccount (division_Deferment_Join_Column);

Comment: There is no "*" in JPQL, I don't think: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

- defm doesn't appear to be a column so change it to * or the columns you want.
- also =: isn't needed here as you're doing a left join syntax.  I belive the := or =: was old ANSI style SQL for joins.

.

```
SELECT *
FROM DefermentAccount defm 
LEFT JOIN defm.division division 
 ON division.divisionID=defm.defermentID
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, but I'm not after the SQL -- I need the JPQL syntax. Thanks- The SQL I originally gave works.

Comment: I think this post might hold the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992834/left-join-on-in-jpql -- but I can't get the query to compile in SQL using WHERE: it is inferred there is no 'ON' in JPQL

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need the ON, or WHERE - it works with just

"SELECT defm, divis FROM DefermentAccount defm LEFT OUTER JOIN defm.division divis"